# How to serve my content with nodejs vm on google cloud

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I created a nodejs virtual machine instance on google cloud (compute engine). I also created 3 mongodb instances on the compute engine. Now I pushed my local application to the google cloud repository. How do I link the app.js file to this server so it starts running the script and serving the files. I already changed the A record of my domain that I registered with godaddy so it's external ip is the same as that of the nodejs server I am running but all I am getting is this page. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami developer here.

You need to copy your files to the remote repository, create the configuration files and after that you have to include that configuration in the configuration of Apache to serve the application. It looks like you have done most of the work, but there may be an error in one of the steps. This guide will help you to configure your application in order to access it properly.

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Custom_Node.js_Application

I hope it helps.

Jota

Comment: I'm not quite sure which step I may have gotten wrong, in the google developers console, I clicked "Cloud Launcher" and then I Node.js and I started a vm, I also have all my application code in the google cloud repository, there is a way to tell my vm to run the app.js when the instance starts by adding a startup.sh file right?

Comment: it says "Run the following commands to create the folders:", right after it tells you what apps is, where do I run these commands?